# SDWebImage ARM 64 Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, sdwebimage

I have been using the SDWebImage for a while in my project and it has been working great. Until, I have upgraded to Xcode 6.0.1 recently and suddenly, everything is a chaos. Everytime, I try to call the method:
 `UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage`

I am getting the unrecognized selector sent to instance crash. I have googled it a bit and the only solution that I can come across is [this](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/622), which in turns gets me to the [issue # 494](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/494). Now, iPhone 5S or not, it's crashing every time. Here are the related settings of my project:
[image]

[image]

Any idea, what I am missing here?